# Does it make sense to add foreign key relationship(s) to many-to-many tables

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table foo (id, name)
create table bar (id, name)
create table foo_bars (foo_id, bar_id)
```

Does it make sense to add foreign key relationship(s) to many-to-many tables. I am assuming we would need a FK relationship for foo_id and bar_id in foo_bars. Can someone confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need foreign keys to ensure data consistency.

Answer (score 2):

It makes a lot of sense. Do it.